# Date when a work item moves into Completed

Tags: rally

I'm looking to calculate Cycle Time based on InProgressDate to Completed Date and not the Accepted Date.  Our Accepted state is driven by our User Acceptance process which sometimes takes longer than we'd like.  I don't see a CompletedDate on the HierarchicalRequirement but perhaps I am missing it.

Am I missing the CompletedDate or should I possibly be looking for this in the Lookback API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that there is no such field as CompletedDate on stories.
Here is a Lookback API query that looks for stories that went trough In-Progress to Completed within the dates specified:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/1111/artifact/snapshot/query.js?find={"_TypeHierarchy":"HierarchicalRequirement","Children":null,"ScheduleState":"Completed","_PreviousValues.ScheduleState":"In-Progress",_ValidFrom: {$gte: "2013-06-01TZ",$lt: "2013-09-01TZ"}},sort:{_ValidFrom:-1}}&fields=["ScheduleState","_PreviousValues"]&hydrate=["_PreviousValues","ScheduleState"]&pagesize:20
```

Here is a fragment of returned results:

```
TotalResultCount": 39,
  "StartIndex": 0,
  "PageSize": 100,
  "ETLDate": "2013-09-17T03:35:02.819Z",
  "Results": [
    {
      "ScheduleState": "Completed",
      "_PreviousValues": {
        "Owner": null,
        "ScheduleState": "In-Progress"
      }
```

Comment: Hi Nickm, I'll give that a try.  Thanks for the query.  I'm running this all from the Ruby rally_api gem so I'm assume that I could get more specific on an individual HierachicalRequirement.  Is that same to say?